# Determining Suitable Concurrent User Simulation for Stress Testing Uploads for a Single Machine

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, gatling, stress-testing

I am conducting stress testing for a upload functionality and need to determe the appropriate number of concurrent users to simulate on a single machine.

We do have multiple machines that we can use, however, **each one machine may have a upload speed limit**. So we **can not let one machine simulate too many users**, otherwise **lots of timeouts** would happen due to **each simulated user not getting enough bandwidth**.

Here are the relevant details:

The total upload speed of one machine is 20 MB/s.
The size of the uploaded file is 1 MB.
Users want to ensure that a file of this size is uploaded within a specific time frame, let's say 5 seconds.

Based on some rough estimations and assumptions, here is the formula I used:

> File Size / Expected Upload Time * 1.5 = Required upload speed per
> thread
>
> Total upload speed / Required upload speed per thread = Number of
> threads that can be simulated on a single machine

For example:

> 1 MB file / 5 s * 1.5 = Required upload speed per thread of at least
> 0.3 MB/s
>
> 20 MB/s / 0.3 MB/s = 66 threads

However, I would like to confirm if my approach is correct and if there are any other factors I should consider in determining the optimal number of concurrent users for this performance testing scenario. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

reference formula: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=8518703D7F80A77C!1937&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!AGxCKFR5UWmFap8

Answer (score 0):

`20 MB/s` doesn't seem to me hitting the limit of your network card, most probably you have 1 gigabit which results into something like 125 megabytes per second.

In general the approach should be following:

1. Set up monitoring of baseline OS health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage, etc.) If you don't have any better idea in mind you can go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
2. Start with 1 virtual user and [gradually increase the load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) until any of monitored metrics starts exceeding i.e. 90% of total available capacity. Once it reached - stop the test and check how many users were online using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) plugin or [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

   This is how many users you can simulate from one machine.